# Node + React dependency issue, peerDependency?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

I'm trying to use this code I found linked off an article online: https://github.com/kangzeroo/Kangzeroos-AWS-Cognito-Boilerplate

The package.json is here: https://github.com/kangzeroo/Kangzeroos-AWS-Cognito-Boilerplate/blob/master/Boilerplate_Frontend/App/package.json

After downloading and running:  `npm install`, I get this warning:

```
$ npm install
...
npm WARN radium@0.18.4 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN Kangzeroos-ES6-React-Redux-Boilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I've been reading about peerDependencies, so I add this to the package.json

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.0"
  }
```

After I add that, now I get this:

```
$ npm install
...
npm WARN Kangzeroos-ES6-React-Redux-Boilerplate@1.0.0 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN radium@0.18.4 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN Kangzeroos-ES6-React-Redux-Boilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I've tried updating the version of react in the main dependencies, and installing multiple versions in the main ones also.  But really, what is the proper way to figure this out and get this to run?  It seems all the version numbers are pinned pretty well.

I know this is a fairly common issue, but man it's super confusing.  Any tips would help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> npm WARN radium@0.18.4 requires a peer of react@^15.3.0 but none was installed.

This means that `radium@0.18.4` requires a peer dependency `react@^15.3.0`.

The one you have listen in your package json is `"react": "^0.14.3"`, so that's why npm complains about that.

The solution would be to update the react version to at least `15.3.0` but probably you can get away without it (it's just a warning and the React API is not changing that much).

> npm WARN Kangzeroos-ES6-React-Redux-Boilerplate@1.0.0 No repository field.

This is just because of this `"repository": "",`. You can safely ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it's not working if I just leave it original.  I get a weird errror which is similar here when running the app: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/radium/issues/884 not sure best way to fix it.

Comment: @Danno also downgrading the **radium** package can be a way to go but you should probably check the `changelog` or open another question for that

Comment: I figured that changing all of the ^ in the package.json to ~ might force all the versions to lock at the ones they were at time of build, but that didn't work either.  Aren't these packages supposed to pull in all the specific dependency versions they need on their own?  Is it possible that it's wedged itself and not able to get it working?  I did try messing with the radium version up and down a bit so far nothing.

Comment: Hey! I got it working.  I went into the top level node_modules folder, then went into radium folder, then added "react": "^15.3.0" into that package.json and did an npm install in side of App/node_modules/radium/ and now it loads.

Answer (score -1):

I got it working. I went into the top level node_modules folder, then went into radium folder, then added `"react": "^15.3.0"` into that package.json as the last item in the "dependencies" section and did an `npm install` inside of App/node_modules/radium/ and now the app loads :+1: